# WiFi Connection Drops After Launching Any Game, Comes Back After Game Is Closed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, gaming

I've been experiencing an odd problem after installing my new GPU (RX 570). Whenever I launch a game my WiFi connection goes from "Connected, Secured" to "Connected, No Internet" or loses the connection completely. Before I had my GPU and was using the iGPU, the same thing would occur if I plugged in a USB Device (Thumbdrive, etc), although games worked fine back then (at a much lower fps obviously). If I run the Windows Network Troubleshooter while a game is running in the background it fails to resolve the problem and says "Windows was unable to automatically detect this network's proxy settings".  I've also found that the same thing happens when running a GPU benchmark, for example Unigine Heaven

Another thing I find odd is that if I connect to my mobile hotspot, all of the problems disappear and everything works perfectly. This would lead me to believe it is a problem with my router-modem combo, however it works perfectly fine with every other device in the house.

Relevant Info:

- My USB WiFi adapter is the DWA-171, I am using this [driver](https://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DWA-171) for
  it.
- Motherboard: Gigabyte B450M S2H (in case it matters)
- The networ kthat I am connected to is 5GHz
- Due to circumstances, Ethernet is not
  an option
- I don't think it is a range/signal quality problem since it
  worked before I had my GPU.

What I've Tried:

- Restart modem-router combo, both through the web interface and by
  unplugging it.
- Re-install USB WiFi adapter drivers and my motherboards LAN drivers.
- Uninstalling the USB WiFi adapter from Device Manager and
  re-installing it.
- Doing a full network reset through the settings app.
- ipconfig /release, ipconfig /renew
- netsh winsock reset
- netsh int ip reset
- Different USB ports (USB 2 and 3)
- Setting the WiFI Adapter to Max Performance in power options
- Not allowing windows to turn off the WiFI adapter in power options
- Using the whole D-link suite and connection manager.
- Updating motherboard BIOS to the newest version (F50)
- Re-installing Windows 10

I've pretty much narrowed it down to if my GPU is under load, my WiFi will drop out.

Comment: What PCIe slot is the video card plugged in to? 1 being closest to I/O ports, 4 furthest.

Comment: The GPU is in slot 2, that's the only x16 slot on my board. Slot 1 & 3 are x1s.

Comment: Power issue? Not enough juice to power your whole PC, and the WiFi adapter probably still has the "Turn this device to save power" setting enabled?

Comment: The WiFi adapter is set to maximum performance, I've turned all the power saving stuff off. I would think its a PSU issue too, however the WiFi works perfect when gaming on a mobile hotspot.

Comment: Gaming through a USB device is pushing the capability of the USB, but you mentioned that you can get online via a mobile hotspot - Do you connect to this wirelessly or just plug it straight into USB?

Comment: I connect wirelessly, just like I would to any other network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, turns out the EMFs generated by my GPU when it is under load were enough to interfere with 5GHz WiFi signal coming from my router. I simply got a USB cable extension and placed the USB WiFi adapter around 2m away from my PC, everything works perfectly now.